# Remove Phoenix OS DarkMatter from a windows-linux dual boot system

Tags: linux, uninstall, dualboot, phoenix

I have followed the instructions from this [link](https://supreme-gamers.com/t/grub-issue.39/post-236). I copied all the files from the ISO to the root directory on Linux partition, then added the OS entry to the grub menu. Now I would like to remove this DarkMatter, but the files i copied are no longer there, assuming they were extracted. Now how do I uninstall completely ?

Comment: Did you move the files or copy the files?  What command exactly did you use to copy the files?

Comment: i copied using the file manager on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed it.
I just had to delete /system . apparently when it was being installed, it treated Linux root directory as its own root directory. Linux and Android have similar folder structures apparently.
Hope it helps someone